# How to skip a counter if database connection cannot be established

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a vb.net program that fills a spreadsheet.  This program runs 3 queries and uses the "location" info to loop through.  I have a basic for next loop.

```
Try
    For icounter = 1 To 15
        Call GetLocationInfo()
        Call Query1()
        Call Query2()
        Call Query3()
    Next icounter
    xlworkbooks.Save()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    xl.Workbooks.Close()
End Try
xl.Workbooks.Close()
```

The problem I have is, lets say location "10" goes down at night, this program will loop through and crap out at 10.  I'd like it to skip a location if it cannot establish a database connection (it should skip all 3 queries for this location and just jump to 'next counter'  Any ideas?

Comment: if  `GetLocationInfo()` was a function that returned a True/False value you could add an IF to skip when pne "goes down"

Comment: @Shmewnix why are you using `Call` ? unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've broken out any VB, but I believe both of these will work:

```
For icounter = 1 To 15
    Try
        Call GetLocationInfo()
        Call Query1()
        Call Query2()
        Call Query3()
    Catch ex1 As Exception
    End Try
 Next icounter
```

OR

```
For icounter = 1 To 15
    Try
        Call GetLocationInfo()
    Catch ex1 As Exception
        Continue For
    End Try
    Call Query1()
    Call Query2()
    Call Query3()
Next icounter
```

Sorry if my syntax is a bit off.

Note that this may require you to rethink your try/catch that exists OUTSIDE of the for loop

Comment: My Try Catch was including the for loop.  I brought it inside the for loop, and this fixed my problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a `try catch` block for each query with the `counter + 1` in each of them

Comment: are you saying the "Counter +1" should go in the Catch section?

Comment: in each try you Query and next row counter +1. if the query is not succesful it will go in the catch and counter will not increase.

Comment: I want them to increment... that's the point... "If site 10 is dead, Go to site 11"

Comment: if you use try catch in for statement, it will continue no matter if for a index was a good try or it went in the catch.

Comment: What should be in the catch?

Comment: nothing. maybe a log if you want to know if something bad happened